# Code is giving me an error: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'related_model'

Tags: python, django

How can I retrieve a list of all foreign keys for a model in Django and access their corresponding models?

I'm trying to loop through all the foreign keys for a model in Django and access the corresponding model for each foreign key. Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model fields

for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields():
    if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
        related_model = field.related_model
```

However, this code is giving me an error: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'related_model'. How can I fix this and successfully retrieve a list of all foreign keys and their corresponding models for MyModel?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please add code snippet instead of images

Answer (score 0):

You access this with:

```
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import ManyToOneRel

for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields():
    if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
        if isinstance(field, ManyToOneRel):
            related_model = field.model
        else:
            related_model = field.related_model
```

The `ManyToOneRel` is a relation that is a `ForeignKey` at another model that targets your model (here `MyModel`), so a `ForeignKey` in "reverse".